# How to add matrix XY axis numbers and XY axes to display

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This is my array and I use numpy in python3.6

```
[[6. 4. 4. 1. 2.]
 [0. 7. 4. 2. 2.]
 [0. 0. 6. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 2. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 2.]]
```

And I want to add x asix and y asix is I1 , I2 , I3 , I4 , I5 like this:

```
    I1 I2 I3 I4 I5
[I1[6. 4. 4. 1. 2.]
 I2[0. 7. 4. 2. 2.]
 I3[0. 0. 6. 0. 1.]
 I4[0. 0. 0. 2. 0.]
 I5[0. 0. 0. 0. 2.]]
```

And  print is:

```
[I1,I2 = 4
I1,I3 = 4
I1,I4 = 1
I1,I5 = 2
I2,I3 = 4
I2,I4 = 2
I2,I5 = 2
I3,I4 = 0
I3,I5 = 1
I4,I5 = 0]
```

How can I do?

Comment: Not without a lot of string formating.  Look at pandas datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible implementation

```
import numpy as np                                                                 

data = np.array([[6, 4, 4, 1, 2],                                                  
[0, 7, 4, 2, 2],                                                                   
 [0, 0, 6, 0, 1],                                                                  
 [0, 0, 0, 2, 0],                                                                  
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 2],])                                                                

m, n = data.shape                                                                  

for i in range(m):                                                                 
    for j in range(i+1, n):                                                        
        print(f'I{i+1}, I{j+1} = {data[i, j]}')
```

Note your example output has a typo. `I4, I5 = 2` should be `I4, I5 = 0`.

Comment: Thank you very much ! this is very good answer!!
And I edit my question! thank you your remind~~